# Sum along absolute values in an Array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum, absolute

My array contains a string in the first row

how can I sum the array from the 2nd row to the Nth/1442th row (as in my example) disregarding the negative signs present in the column?

for example, my code for an array called `data2` is:

```
S = sum(data2(2,15):data2(1442,15));
```

so sum all of the elements from row 2 to row 1442 in column 15.
This doesn't work but it also does not have anything to deal with the absolute value of whatever row its checking

data is from  a .csv:[image]

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the data looks like?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104069213/Data.png 

Here's an image of the column. It's from a .csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
sum(abs(data(2:1442,15)));
```

The `abs` function will find the absolute value of each value in the array (i.e. disregard the negative sign). `data(2:1442,15)` will grab rows 2-1442 of the 15th column, as you wanted.

EDIT: apparently `data` is a cell array, so you could do the following, I think:

```
sum(abs([data{2:1442,15}]));
```

Comment: `??? Undefined function or method 'abs' for input arguments of type
'cell'.

Error in ==> SunPathScriptRoof at 868
GlobalRadiationSum = sum(abs(data2(2:1442,15)));`

However, when I type abs(-1) in command window, it returns 1. So the in-built function must be installed correctly.

Also, the file is called data2 in case you think that I was writing a typo.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't aware that data was a cell array. Check my edit.

Comment: Got it. That works. Thanks. Apologies for mis-communication of array type.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it looks like you have a constant column so

```
data2(2,15) = -0.02
```

and further down

```
data2(1442,15) = -0.02 %(I would assume)
```

So when you form:

```
data2(2,15):data2(1442,15)
```

this is essential like trying to create an array but of a single value since:

```
-0.02:-0.02

ans =

   -0.0200
```

which of course gives:

```
>> sum(-0.02:-0.02)

ans =

   -0.0200
```

What you want should be more like:

```
sum(data2(2:1442,15))
```

That way, the index: 2:1442, forms a vector of all the row references for you.

To disregard the negative values:

```
your answer = sum(abs(data2(2:1442,15)))
```

**EDIT:  For a cell array this works:**

```
sum(abs(cell2mat(data2(2:1442,15))))
```